# Set request scope object on a thread (jersey injection)

Tags: java, multithreading, dependency-injection, jersey

I am spawning multiple threads as part of a request and i want to make sure the request scoped Metrics object is set for all the child threads. How can we do this in my service that uess jersey injection?

I tried doing [RequestScope.runInScope()](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/core-common/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/process/internal/RequestScope.java#L359) , unfortunately that resets the request cope after the thread run completes so all the metrics changes done in the child thread is lost.

Is there a better way to pass my request scope to the thread or just specifically set a request scope object on my thread?